# How do I implement touch event for my application?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, testing, touch

I want to implement touch event in my Win-Form application. Touch events for buttons, list, combo box and check box.  Any idea how do I implement it ? I couldn't find any resources for the same.

I just want my application to be completely compatible with the touch screen Tablets. I use .NET 3.5 and don't see any relevant event handlers. Am I missing any thing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing something.

I think the "touch" event you are looking for is in fact a "single click" if running win forms on a tablet.

Handle the OnClick event.

Comment: so handle "Click" event for all the components to make it response to touch events. Cool. I will add it, test it and update you with the progress/problems. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Tvd yes, I think a double tap is a double click, etc. a touch is just a mouse click. Thats how ít always worked when I wrote touchscreen POS software.

Comment: Thanks, 
   I implemented Click event wherever I hadn't. In combobox, am wondering how to get an item selected by touch. Have already implemented "SelectedIndexChanged", but how do I make the item selected on touching an item ? And similar for  selecting row in DataGridView. Have set it properties (RowTemplate-DefaultCellStyle) and that's how it gets selected at present and no Click is required to implement.

Comment: Any idea how to test the application without a touch screen ? I mean I could find Multitouch Simulator (http://michaelsync.net/2010/04/06/step-by-step-tutorial-installing-multi-touch-simulator-for-silverlight-phone-7) that can be used to test WPF application wihtou touch screen capability. But mine is Win-Form app. How can I test if the touch facility is working properly without having a touch screen monitor ??

Comment: @Tvd in winforms i'm pretty sure you can just use single mouse clicks. what OS will you be using?

Comment: My app is compatible with windows > 98 to win 7, Vista & 32 & 64 bit OS. .NET 3.5 am using. For development my OS is Win 7 32 bit.

Comment: @Tvd then testing as click=touch should be fine

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by using Selecting event handler dor respective controls

Comment: Which touch event handler to use for Win-Forms app to achieve the same ?

Comment: Tell me wht u wanted to do with form

Comment: I think the Q says clearly what I am looking for. All I want is the controls to respond on touch events in my application. Bt doing so just want to let my app run perfectly well with users using Tablets - where normally the only control is touch & no mouse or keyboard.

Comment: But,i did not say which control u wanna respond for?